# Check how many 1 are in the column of a matrix #minizinc

Tags: authentication, constraints, constraint-programming, minizinc

Given a matrix Z[n,m]:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
```

I'd like to check how many "1" there are in the different columns of the matrix. So given k=1 in this case, the problem should be unsatisfiable since in the column there are 2 "1", so "number of 1">k. I tried in this way but it doesn't work:

```
constraint forall(i in n, j in m) forall(k in n) k<=( Z[i,j]\/Z[k,j])
```

Where am I wrong?

In the case I have this variables how I can do?

```
int b;
int: k;
set of int: PEOPLE = 1..p;      
set of int: STOPS = 1..s;  
array [1..b, PEOPLE, STOPS] of var bool: Z;


Z[1]
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0

Z[2]
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0

p = 5;
s =5;
k=1;
b=2;
```

So in this case the result should be:

```
Z[1]: 1 0 1 0 0 , the number of "1" is 2, "2 > K"
Z[2]: 0 1 0 0 0, the number of "1" is 1, "1<=K"
UNSATISFIABLE
```

Comment: Is the constraint that there can be atmost one 1 per column?

Comment: no, with the constraint that I wrote above I was trying to sum the "1" of each column and then count how many "1" there are. I'd like to have as results 2 since there are just "1" in the first column and "1" in the third column. Then compare this number with "k".

Comment: What do you expect the solution would be? Given your description it will just  give false ("UNSATISFIED") since the constraint just check the constraint.  Also, can you show the complete code? The constraint has several syntactic errors.

To enforce that the number of 1s in a column is atmost k, you can do:
forall(j in 1..n) ( sum([Z[i,j] | i in 1..m]) <= k )

If you want to show the number of 1s in each column you have to define an array of length m which contains the sum of the j'th column...

Comment: @hakank sorry I didn't see you already posted the solution here (:

Answer (score 1):

I just solved in this way:

```
array [1..b, STOPS] of var bool: M;
constraint forall (m in 1..b) ( forall (j in STOPS) (  M[m,j]= exists([Z[m,i,j] | i in PEOPLE ])));
constraint forall (m in 1..b) ( let {
            var int: s = sum (j in STOPS)(M[m,j]>0);
        } in
            s <= t  );
```

thank you all for the answers :)